# Why is this hair particle system not properly into account the 'density' vertex group?

Tags: particles, vertex-groups

Having trouble with hair particle system on a vertex group on version 2.74.

I have a single head mesh (post mirror-apply, already checked MeshLint and normals) with multires modifier on. I created a beard vertex group to control the area to grow my beard/mustache.

[image]

When I specify my beard vertex group under "density", the generated hair only stays in the vertex group area on one half of the mesh, and spreads outside the area and onto parts of the face, neck, and ears in the other half.

[image: only with density specified]

When I specify both "density" and "length" to my beard vertex group, the generated hair does stay in the vertex group area on both halves of the head mesh, but there are glaring bald spots despite having "Even Distribution" toggled on.

[image]

I'm hesitant on resorting to replicating and separating parts of my mesh in order to control hair growth, which gives me the expected correct behavior. How do I do this without resorting to this hack?

[image]

Not sure if anyone could provide any assistance on my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the **Weight Paint** mode to create your vertex group.
Make sure you **Apply Transforms** on your mesh aswell.

Regarding "**separating part**", creating 'scalps', I think it is a better way to go especially when using animated characters.

[image: Vertex WeightPaint]

Post a **blend file** if you still struggle.

EDIT: The Particle tool has a known bug when used with subdivision surfaces, and Multires. So it's "normal" and is being solved.
(SOURCE: https://soundcloud.com/blender-institute/podcast-ep-006-flexirig @ 12:50mn)

Comment: I had a similar problem. Applying subdivision surface really helped.

Comment: I'm also having problems relating this issue.
It also occurs when you have a bevel modifier primarily to the particle system.

Comment: @Delagone what is the order of your modifiers in the stack?

Comment: @Akelian Like I mentioned, I first added a bevel modifier followed by a particle system. Had this problem occuring on several projects since Cycles supported GPU hair rendering. Didn't know why but after reading this question it has come apparent that this is a bug.